# XSD code generator empty nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I have been provided an XSD file that I have generated code from using XSD.exe but it is not functioning in the way that I'm expecting.

```
    <xsd:element name="Claims">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Claim" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="ClaimDate" type="xsd:dateTime" />
                <xsd:element name="ClaimDesc" type="xsd:string" />
                ....
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

The expectation is that if there are no claims, then an empty  node is sent through but the generated code comes out as

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Claim", IsNullable=false)]
public QuoteRequestClaim[] Claims {
    get {
        return this.claimsField;
    }
    set {
        this.claimsField = value;
    }
}
```

meaning that I cannot pass this empty node through. Is this a quirk in XSD.exe or does the XSD need to be modified to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this myself. The XSD that I had been provided with needed changing to

```
<xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      <xsd:element name="Claim">
      </xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
```

The minOccurs and the maxOccurs were in the wrong place.